# Set RegisterValue to default value in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to set a register value to a specific string (true) if a feature is selected, or set it to a default value (false) if not selected.
I've tried the following, but i doesn't seems to work :-(

```
    <Component Id="ExampleFalseComponent">
        <Condition><![CDATA[Feature1 = "3" ]]></Condition>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="path" Name="examplevalue" Type="string" Value="false" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="ExampleTrueComponent">
        <Condition><![CDATA[Feature1 < "3" ]]></Condition>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="path" Name="examplevalue" Type="string" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Feature Id="Feature1" Title="Some text string" Absent="allow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" Display="collapse" Level="3">
        <ComponentRef Id="ExampleFalseComponent"/>
        <ComponentRef Id="ExampleTrueComponent"/>
    </Feature>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a SetProperty element scheduled in the execute sequence after cost finalize to set SomeProperty to "true" when your condition evaluates to true.  Then use [SomeProperty] in your RegistryValue.

Also note that during a first install the feature will be installing but not yet installed and during a repair your feature will be installed but not installing so write your condition accordingly.